# Difference between these array declarations?

Tags: arrays, c

What is the difference between these array declaration?

- char array[const static 4];
- const static char array[4];

Comment: The first one is not valid C.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the first one? It's a number. Is it going to change somehow while declaring the array?

Comment: @kaylum Actually it is *if* it's a function parameter.

Comment: @dbush Fair point, although (of course) a function parameter declaration must not terminate in a semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

The first declaration, `char array[const static 4];`, is not a valid declaration in C. Per C 6.7.6.2 1, qualifiers inside `[` and `]` may appear only in function parameter declarations.

If this appears as a function parameter declaration, as in `void foo(char array[const static 4])`, then it means:

- `array` is an array of 4 `char`, but it will adjusted to be a pointer to `char`.
- That pointer will be `const` qualified, meaning it should not be modified.
- When the function is called, the pointer must point to the first of at least 4 `char` objects.

Note that the `const` indicates that the pointer is `const` qualified, not that the `char` objects it points to are `const` qualified.

The second declaration, `const static char array[4];`, means `array` is an array of 4 `const` `char` that have static storage duration, meaning memory will be reserved for them throughout the entire execution of the program. If the declaration appears outside of a function, the `static` also means that the identifier `array` will have internal linkage. (If it appears inside a function, the identifier has no linkage, regardless of the `static`.)

Thus, the `static` has completely different meanings between the two declarations. In the first, it imposes a requirement on the number of elements in the array. In the second, it affects storage duration (when the memory is reserved for the array) and possibly linkage (how the name is connected to other occurrences of the same name).

The `const` has similar meanings in the two declarations, but it applies to different parts. In the first, it applies to the pointer that is declared. In the second, it applies to the elements of the array.